# JSONException : End of input at character 0 of , the response return 0?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I'm trying to use `JSONArray` so i follow some tutorials and edit it, here's my code.

```
private void showData(final String sid) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    JsonArrayRequest jObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(
            PORT_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            final ArrayList<Inventory> inventory = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String date = jObj.getString("date");
                    String code = jObj.getString("codesec");
                    String name = jObj.getString("secname");
                    String vol = jObj.getString("volume");

                    Inventory in = new Inventory();
                    in.setDate(date);
                    in.setCode(code);
                    in.setName(name);
                    in.setVol(vol);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    SimpleTableDataAdapter adapter = new SimpleTableDataAdapter(c, new TableHelper(c).DataArray(inventory));
                    tableView.setDataAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("sid", sid);
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(jObjReq);
}
```

and this output that i want to show (assuming the sid already inputed)

```
[
  {
    "0": "8",
    "1": "1305199706",
    "2": "2017-10-10",
    "3": "SME",
    "4": "Super Mechanic Electro",
    "5": "500",
    "id": "8",
    "sid": "1305199706",
    "date": "2017-10-10",
    "codesec": "SME",
    "secname": "Super Mechanic Electro",
    "volume": "500"
  },
  {
    "0": "9",
    "1": "1305199706",
    "2": "2017-10-11",
    "3": "RRXE",
    "4": "Recontruction Rex Expert",
    "5": "10,000",
    "id": "9",
    "sid": "1305199706",
    "date": "2017-10-11",
    "codesec": "RRXE",
    "secname": "Recontruction Rex Expert",
    "volume": "10,000"
  }
]
```

and its turn `error org.json.JSONException :  End of input at character 0` on logcat. i dont know what i miss...

Comment: Have you debug your code? response is proper or not check?

Comment: what is the `value` of  `sid` and also provide `URL`

Comment: can you please provide the api url in the post which you are using

Comment: @HarishPenta the api url ? i using localhost

Comment: @VishalYadav 1305199706 (String) , i using localhost and it shows the array above

Comment: @RavenNyo When you are using localhost your address should be 10.0.2.2. replace localhost with 10.0.2.2 in your url

Comment: since you are using localhost so please use the default IP 10.0.2.2 and please provide the logcat

Comment: I am not able to recognise the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a local server and debugging from emulator . Replace `localhost` with `10.0.2.2` in your URL.

If you are using a phone which is connected in the same network replace `localhost` with `IP Address` of your local server in your URL

The error is because your API doesn't return any value/JSON to the calling function

Check your URL is working and that URL returns value

Comment: @RavenNyo check weather you have added the internet permission

Comment: yes i've been added the internet permission, the other function like register & login works fine

Comment: @RavenNyo When you are using localhost your address should be 10.0.2.2. replace localhost with 10.0.2.2 in your url

Comment: If you are testing you app on mobile the it should connect to the same network otherwise it will give problem.

Comment: Yes it will give the error. Test the app from emulator. If you are using a phone that is connected to the same network then replace localhost with IP address of your server (your pc) @NaveedAkhtar

Comment: @SushinPv yes, adb from android studio

Comment: @RavenNyo you are getting same error in emulator also ? Then please paste your server code here

Comment: @RavenNyo End of input at character 0 comes when the server code execute and it doesn't return any data to android volley. So check weather your code return correct value in normal  browser. If you are sending any value from android to server and if the value has space then replace all space with %20 ` requestaUri.replace all(" "," %20");`

Answer (score 0):

You can check length of data receiving from server by Log.
Check length of array by using `Log.d("TAG","Length :- "+response.length());`
If length is 0 then check url which you are calling. Hope it will help you.

Comment: i dont know how to get the response , it end and error in this line : JsonArrayRequest jObjReq = new JsonArrayRequest(PORT_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() and i've been using localhost and im sure i didnt mistype

Comment: Check api on Post Man and see weather api is giving response or not.